# Can someone tell whether this Russian swear word derives from German?

Tags: этимология, мат, other-languages

*Лох* is a word that I heard among Russians and Ukrainians who never visited Germany. So it’s not quite clear whether the German language is the origin. Can anyone shed any light on the origin of this word?

My *guess* would be it derives from the German word (Arsch)loch (by sound in Cyrillic it would be approx. [арш-лох]), literally for (ass)hole. But if possible I’d like to see some kind of authoritative answer to the question.

I’ve also heard that German is one of the few languages where most swear words derive from fecal context, where in other languages offensive terms used in a similar way would be derived from a sexual context. This would actually be an argument *for* the theory that it derives from German, but again, it’s more hearsay than anything.

Comment: I cannot attest analytically whether German has higher incidence of excrement-based swearing, but as I’ve read in [_Euphemania: Our Love Affair with Euphemisms_](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8527586-euphemania), most common tabooed topics (and hence the need for euphemisms) were sex, excrement, death, war (not necessarily in this order, depending on the time period and culture), pretty much across the board. The author did focus on English, but he did offer examples from other languages, and he did not mention any propensity for the subject by the Germans.

Comment: Also, _лох_ is not really a swear word. It is a disparaging term, usually for the person who doesn’t know what they are doing, and easily swindled. Surely crass sounding, but nowhere near the level of real spicy language.

Comment: [Лох — Неотесанный, неуклюжий человек, увалень, простак; провинциал; неопытный молокосос, непрофессионал.](http://gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_6597)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nobody knows where it comes from. The only thing known for sure (as it *is* a popular theory) is that it **isn't** derived from the German "Loch".

[Wiktionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F_3) states that it may be a shortened version of the word `лопух` (in its informal meaning, "simpleton").

Then, there's [Vasmer](http://vasmer.narod.ru/p373.htm). His descriptions of the word `лох` do not include the colloquial meaning, but he has an entry for the word `лоха`, which is a colloquial word in Pskov and Tver for a stupid woman. Vasmer assumes that it can come from `лошь` which means "bad". And he has an entry for `лашуня` which means also something like "simpleton" or just "fool". Vasmer assumes that this word is also dervied from `лошь`.

And there's also [Lurkmore](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D1%85#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.85.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B2.D1.8B.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F) that has an impressive list of supposed origins of the word `лох`. I won't translate them, as they are most likely all invalid - examples of folk etymology. The version that it originates in German, being derived from `Arschloch` is also there.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Several versions are presented in [http://forum.lingvo.ru](http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?bid=18&tid=1035). I prefer version German (Ein Loch in dem Kopf) -> Jiddisch -> Russian.

Answer (score 0):

Definately not. You may find this word, together with many others, in В. И. Даль и тайные языки в России (2004) by В. Д Бондалетов, Владимир Иванович Даль.

All of a sudden, this word (and many others) are presented there like - yes! - borrowings from Finno-Ugric languages of peoples settled in NW Russia.

The word was a part of Ofenya slang and meant then мужик, обыватель, не-офеня.

The source word is Finno-Ugric ***lohi*** meaning *salmon*. The meaning in Ofenya slang was metonimical and stood for salmons being easy capture during spawning season.